# XCode says method does not override any method in Superclass for method editActionsForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create custom row action for my tableview program.
In order to do that I learned that I have to implement the table view function with `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`. But Xcode says there is no method to override in the superclass.

Below is the code in question

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:
    NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject] {}
```

Comment: Does your view controller inherit from UIViewController or from UITableViewController?

Comment: It inherits from UITabnleViewController. I am trying to create a custom table view.The method is there in apple's API documentation but i can't seem to override it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. If I add that function (including "override") to the table view controller in a standard Xcode 6.4 Master-Detail Application template project then it compiles without problems.

Comment: Yeah, i figured out the problem.Turns out they replaced the return type [AnyObject] with [UITableViewRowAction]. Then it works. I am using Xcode 7.0 Beta 5. But the [AnyObject] return type works in xcode 6.4. Any idea why that is? And thank you so much for your effort to help. Cheers

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you think that your solution is of some value for future readers then you should write you own answer now. Otherwise you can delete the question :)